# Error al tratar de instalar la lib Channels y channels_redist

Tags: python, django

Hola estoy empezando a estudiar todo el tema de los websockets y channels en django, y encontre un proyecto en internet para crear un chat asincronico con django.

El primer paso es cargar los requeriments.txt.

En ese paso es el problema xd.

Cuando va a tratar de instalar la lib channels, a mitad de la instalacion como parte del proceso intenta instalar la lib Twisted, donde da el siguiente error.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
  command: 'c:\nueva carpeta\django\chat\mi_web\entorno\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-croewl9b\\twisted_d567dd2e3271452d9166d9618f5b2b4e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-croewl9b\\twisted_d567dd2e3271452d9166d9618f5b2b4e\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-jmkwbqjf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\nueva carpeta\django\chat\mi_web\entorno\include\site\python3.9\twisted'
  cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-croewl9b\twisted_d567dd2e3271452d9166d9618f5b2b4e\

Complete output (947 lines):
..... 947 lineas de intentos fallidos(No podia ponerlas todas)

building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\nueva carpeta\django\chat\mi_web\entorno\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-croewl9b\\twisted_d567dd2e3271452d9166d9618f5b2b4e\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-croewl9b\\twisted_d567dd2e3271452d9166d9618f5b2b4e\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-jmkwbqjf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\nueva carpeta\django\chat\mi_web\entorno\include\site\python3.9\twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Lo primero que pense que podria se era la siguiente linea. Pero no es porque tengo instaladas todas las versiones necesarias de Microsoft Visual C++ en mi pc.

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

Solucione este error descargando el wheel Twisted e instalandolo manualmente, pero no entiendo la necesidad de hacerlo asi. Necesito una explicacion al respecto.

Luego de solucionar ese error surge otro del mismo estilo en la instalacion de la lib channels_redis.
A mitad de la instalacion trata de instalar un componente que se llama hiredis. Y da el siguiente error

```
Running setup.py install for hiredis ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\nueva carpeta\django\chat\mi_web\entorno\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j2ibj3kc\\hiredis_6792d9fd107940ec8674c076f3c52ba5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j2ibj3kc\\hiredis_6792d9fd107940ec8674c076f3c52ba5\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-exmq8rfr\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\nueva carpeta\django\chat\mi_web\entorno\include\site\python3.9\hiredis'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j2ibj3kc\hiredis_6792d9fd107940ec8674c076f3c52ba5\
    Complete output (13 lines):
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j2ibj3kc\hiredis_6792d9fd107940ec8674c076f3c52ba5\setup.py:7: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
      import sys, imp, os, glob, io
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\hiredis
    copying hiredis\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\hiredis
    copying hiredis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\hiredis
    running build_ext
    building 'hiredis.hiredis' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\nueva carpeta\django\chat\mi_web\entorno\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j2ibj3kc\\hiredis_6792d9fd107940ec8674c076f3c52ba5\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j2ibj3kc\\hiredis_6792d9fd107940ec8674c076f3c52ba5\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-exmq8rfr\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\nueva carpeta\django\chat\mi_web\entorno\include\site\python3.9\hiredis' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Trate de solucionarlo de la misma forma que Twisted(Instalandolo manualmente, pero no me deja)

Alguna explicacion. Gracias de atemano

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver este problema de la siguiente forma. Como ya comente arriba.
Cuando iba a instalar channels, me daba un error a mitad de instalacion porque no lograba instalar un componente llamado Twisted. Esto lo solucione descargando el wheel e instalandolo manual.

Cuando trataba de hacer lo mismo con el error que me daba al intentar instalar channels_redis, porque no lograba instalar el componente hiredis, me daba un error porque no era soportado en mi plataforma.

Yo estaba usando la ultima version de python. Tuve que usar una mas antigua, y con esto solucione el problema. Instale manual los wheels twisted e hiredis, y luego instale channels y channels_redis sin problemas.